# How to convert 2D list into dataframe

Tags: python, list, dataframe, for-loop

I have a python code that convert 2D list into pandas dataframe. Where the result is a dataframe with 2 records.

What i expect is to make all the data in one single row where each value is in a different column.

How can i make this happen ?

```
import pandas as pd
a = [[1,2],[3,5,6]]
print(type(a))

for b in a:
    for j in b:
        print(j)

dt=zip(a)
df=pd.DataFrame(dt,columns=["d"])
print(type(df))
print(df)
```

Result
[image]

Comment: A dataframe can be created using a dictionary. It's not clear for me how you want to compose this, but you can create a dictionary of how you would like it to look like and then simply create a dataframe using `pd.DataFrame(data = dictionary)`

Comment: @AlexandruDuDu That is not correct. A list of list can also be used.

Comment: khaled , the number of columns and your list max size must match.

Comment: So based on your answer if i have a list   i must convert it first into dictionary than create the dataframe.

Comment: I didn't say it can `ONLY` be created using a dictionary. I'm saying it's the better to do so since you can have a better overview at how it will look like

Comment: did you mix up column and row? you only provide one column header - looks as if you want 1 column and 5 rows?

Comment: what i want is   the opposite 1 row and 5 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably isn't the most efficient way but the following code:

```
a = [[1,2],[3,5,6]]
one_d_list = [x for b in a for x in b]

df = pd.DataFrame(one_d_list, index= ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
df.transpose()
```

will return the following dataframe:

```
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  2  3  5  6
```

EDIT following question in comments:

```
b = [[1,2,3,4,5,1,4,7,8,9]]

b_1 = b[0][:5]
b_2 = b[0][5:]

pd.DataFrame([b_1, b_2], columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
```

Returns:

```
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  2  3  4  5
1  1  4  7  8  9
```

Comment: How to add **columns name** to the created df? 
And what if i have more than **1 row**  with the same number of columns?

Comment: @khaledM_dev I have edited the code to add column names. As for your second point, I'm not entirely sure what you mean, unless you are saying that you have an additional 2d list that you want to add to the df above, in which case you could use pd.concat (see documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html )

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
No what i meant is let say that each 5 values must be considerate as 1 record 
Like : `[[1,2,3,4,5,1,4,7,8,9]]` in the above list result must be `2 rows 5 columns`

Comment: @khaledM_dev In this case you may want to consider storing data in another structure, as was highlighted above, as your data is stored in inconsistent ways that may be problematic as your data grows in size. A quick & dirty solution to your question however would be to split the list via indexing e.g., list[0][:5] and then create a dataset from this var. or merge with one already created.

Comment: @khaledM_dev I have added code above as a very quick method to solving your problem.

Comment: When you said **in nanother structure**  you mean `dictionary`??

Comment: @khaledM_dev Yes if there is consistency in the method you are using to store data.